# List item click check the check placed in listview in android

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, android-listview

I have a task. I listed some listview in subjectlist. In a particular list item, i put textview and checkbox. My problem is, Whenever i click on the listitem(single item of list) it should check the checkbox respectively. I am using listadpter to display the subject list kindly help me.

```
    heading_txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.heading_txt);
    selectall_txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.selectall_txt);

    ListViewAdapter adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this,
                R.layout.institutionitem, clgList, false, position);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);




        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int position, long arg3) {
            System.out.println("position value is-->" + position);
            ListViewAdapter adapter = new ListViewAdapter(
                    InstitutionActivity.this, R.layout.institutionitem,
                    clgList, Check, position);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
    });
```

and list adapter

```
        public ListViewAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
        ArrayList<String> data, boolean check, int position) {

    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
    this.Check = check;
    this.pos = position;
    System.out.println("printdata" + data);
    System.out.println("position value " + position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return data.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {

    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {

    return 0;
}

public static class listHolder {
    TextView college_name;

}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    listHolder holder = null;
    if (row == null) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new listHolder();
        holder.college_name = (TextView) row
                .findViewById(R.id.college_name);
        college_checkb = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.college_chk);

        college_checkb
                .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                            boolean isChecked) {

                        if (isChecked == true) {

                            InstitutionActivity.itemPos.add(data
                                    .get(position));
                            // System.out.println("POSITION checked");

                        } else {

                            // System.out.println("POSITION uncheked");
                            InstitutionActivity.itemPos.remove(data
                                    .get(position));
                        }

                    }
                });

        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (listHolder) row.getTag();

    }

    holder.college_name.setText(data.get(position));
    return row;

}
```

Comment: what is the problem? you don't need `listView.setAdapter(adapter);` on itemClick, just call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: Is there only 1 checkbox in the whole list or each list item has a checkbox?

Comment: No sir, there are multiple checkbox items in the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution

```
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            System.out.println("checcked item" + position);
            Log.e("Check ITEM", "" + position);

            CheckBox c = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.sub_chk);

                if (c.isChecked()) {
                    c.setChecked(false);

                } else {
                    c.setChecked(true);

            }

        }
    });
```